# ServiceNow: how to restrict the visibility of Business Services?

Tags: itil

I need to restrict the list of business services, visible to users in self-service portal and incident page. User should only see the services, available for him.

I've added Business service -> users supported related list to the Group Form. This is a place, where I'm adding the services, that must be available for the user. Both in service catalog record producer and incident form, for the field "business service", I've set the simple reference qualifier, User supported is (dynamic) one of my support groups.

Now the problem is, that "Users supported" accepts the only one group. Meaning, only one service can be linked to a single group (1 to 1) relationship. I can't have a multiple groups, where there is the same Business Service added to "Users supported" list (this is required in my case).

May someone please help with an idea on how to manage the requirement?

1. how to properly manage the relationship between group and business service (having the option to maintain many-to-many relationship)
2. how to filter out the required services in portal and incident form.

Answer (score 1):

1. Manage one-many relationship
   You can use [Glide list items](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/administer/tablet_and_mobile_ui/task/t_GlideListItems.html) that use the `glide_list` field type, such as watch lists.
2. For related list, you can use your own [defined list](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-platform-user-interface/page/administer/form-administration/task/t_CreateDefinedRelatedLists.html) which allows you to have complex relationships between record and lists.